# Error deploying a custom image with the crunchydata postgres operator

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, crunchy-postgresql-operator

I've created a custom image based on `timescaledb` where I've installed `wal2json` and I'm trying to deploy it on my kubernetes cluster using the crunchydata-postgres-operator. I've managed to set everything up except credentials to access the database.

I'm trying to create the pgo cluster with the following command:

```sh
pgo create cluster my-db --ccp-image-prefix="eu.gcr.io/<project-id>" --ccp-image="timescale-custom" -c latest  -d <dbname> -u <username> --password="<my_password>"
```

This command executes successfully, but the database deployment enters a `CrashLoopBackOff` because of the following error:

```sh
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
       See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
       https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

Seeing this I tried to set the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` and `POSTGRES_USER` in the Dockerfile, but this does not alleviate the problem?

I know that usually these environment variables are set in the k8s `deployment.yaml` or in `docker-compose.yml`. But even though the postgres operator has some default credentials they don't seem to be applied to the container?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:12 AS build
ENV VERSION 1_0
RUN buildDeps="curl build-essential ca-certificates git   pkg-config glib2.0 postgresql-server-dev-$PG_MAJOR" \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  ${buildDeps} \
    && echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libc++1 postgresql-server-dev-$PG_MAJOR \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/build \
    && curl -o /tmp/build/${VERSIONN}.tar.gz -SL "https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json/archive/wal2json_${VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && cd /tmp/build/ \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/build/${VERSIONN}.tar.gz -C /tmp/build/ \
    && cd /tmp/build/wal2json-wal2json_${VERSION} \
    && make && make install \
    && mkdir /outputs \
    && cp wal2json.so /outputs/ \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf /tmp/build \
    && apt-get remove -y --purge ${buildDeps} \
    && apt-get autoremove -y --purge \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
FROM timescale/timescaledb:1.7.4-pg12
COPY --from=build /outputs/wal2json.so /usr/local/lib/postgresql/
RUN echo "host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
ENV POSTGRES_USER=<username> POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<password>
```

Edit:

After running the same command with the `--debug` flag I've received this output:

```
DEBU[0000] debug flag is set to true
DEBU[0000] in initConfig with url=https://127.0.0.1:8443
DEBU[0000] using PGO_NAMESPACE env var pgo
DEBU[0000] GetSessionCredentials called
DEBU[0000] PGOUSER environment variable is being used at /home/mycloud/.pgo/pgo/pgouser
DEBU[0000] pgouser file found at /home/mycloud/.pgo/pgo/pgouser contains admin:examplepassword
DEBU[0000] [admin examplepassword]
DEBU[0000] username=[admin] password=[examplepassword]
DEBU[0000] setting up httpclient with TLS
DEBU[0000] GetTLSTransport called
DEBU[0000] create cluster called
DEBU[0000] IsValidForResourceName: my-db
DEBU[0000] createCluster called...[https://127.0.0.1:8443/clusters]
DEBU[0000] &{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Length:[193] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Sat, 09 Jan 2021 19:56:05 GMT] Www-Authenticate:[Basic realm="Restricted"]] 0xc00017c080 193 [] false false map[]
```

Comment: have you inspected the resulting Pods or Deployments to see what the operator actually created, including any Secret or ConfigMaps that are injected, possibly overriding your `ENV` statements? Similarly, does the `pgo` command have a `--debug` verbosity that might inform you of what it is actually doing?

Comment: @mdaniel I've added the debug output, but from the looks of it the deployment itself went fine

Comment: @mdaniel after inspecting the resources produces, it appears that pgo just creates secrets based off the credentials you pass into the cli, it kinda looks like the issue is that your credentials are not getting passed into the container image as env variables in the `k8s deployment.yaml`